# Does Console.WriteLine cause a performance penalty even when the console is not visible? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a console application with lots of `WriteLine()` functions, this application should also run as a "service" (a scheduled task, the user is not logged in when it runs).

In this case, there is no actual cmd window to show. Will `Console.WriteLine()` still cause a noticeable performance penalty in such a case?

Comment: No, it does not. Try hiding the console window next time you run a program that is slow due to console output, and see how much faster it is going to finish its output when console is off screen.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight is right but writes still have a perf impact. I believe they are still transmitted into csrss.exe so that csrss can draw the console on request. Use PerfView to profile that easily.

Comment: I remember that using async task will terminate the performance affect of writeline. A simple test was to write from 1 to one billion. With async task it completed really fast in cuple of seconds.but Im not sure if it did print all the numbers

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yeah, it did not print all numbers :) Because you didn't wait for those tasks. Async does not make IOs faster. It makes them slower.

Comment: Define "noticeable". Of course any code which executes will cause a performance penalty. 15 years ago Console.WriteLine() was a significant slowdown, but doubtless things are better these days. Suck it and see :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes** it will cause performance penalty even when the console is not visible

my experiment was running this piece of code with the console visible and again with the console hidden and measure the performance

first run Console **Visible** **24683** Millisecond
second run Console **Visible** **23363** Millisecond

first run Console **Hidden** **167** Millisecond
second run Console **Hidden** **162** Millisecond

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteMilionLines();
    }

    static void WriteMilionLines()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        sw.Stop();

        string message = "ElapsedMilliseconds" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\log.txt", message);
    }
```

By commenting `Console.WriteLine(i);` line it will take Zero millisec

Comment: A 150x reduction does not seem little to me.

Comment: If you comment out Console.WriteLine(i) , compiler will figure out that there is no need for a loop and it will treat the code as there is no loop at all...

Comment: This only tests the pure Console.WriteLine in isolation, which obviously will make huge differences. But in real code there is alot more happening apart from Console-Calls so the difference will be negligible.
The answer should be NO since the drawback is not **noticable**, and that is what OP asked.

Comment: You could always try to put your Console.WriteLine code inside "#if DEBUG" tags. That way you shouldn't have performance penalty in release code.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't be noticeable. Unless your application does 99% `Console.WriteLine()` and barely anything else, the difference will be negligible.

If you still worry about performance, you could wrap Console-Calls into a method that you have control over and measure the total time your application went through and even introduce a switch (bool variable) to control its calls.